# Create a table in android via webview or database?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, webview

I am writing an app for a football fanclub and wanted to ask how I can display a football table in my app with the current standings, point goal difference and so on. I will create the table on my website but I don't know how to call it in my app, and respond to the changes I make online.
Now I had two ideas but I would like to know which one would be easier and how to implement them.

1. Should I do it with a webview that when online shows the table from the website and when offline shows a cached version?
2. Or should I somehow do it with a local database?
3. Or suggest something that would be even better/easier?

[image: How the table will look like]

Answer (score 0):

the best practice as i do, is to make a local database for this app,
then call a webservice to get information from the server that fills the web page as xml form, finally parse the xml and insert values into your database.